# Detect dark mode in SWT or Eclipse RCP application?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

How can I determine from code whether the SWT/RCP application it's running is being presented in a dark theme?

What I've tried so far:

- The method `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.isSystemDarkTheme()` reports whether the *operating system* prefers dark mode. However, I've observed an application running in light mode even when that method returns true.
- Get the Color for something like `SWT.COLOR_LIST_BACKGROUND`, convert it to HSB, and check its brightness. Works, but seems roundabout.

Comment: I don't think there is any API for this. Display has a package private `appAppearance` field. On macOS `org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS` has an `isAppDarkAppearance()` method.

Comment: The Javadoc of `Display.isSystemDarkTheme()` explains it quite well, doesn't it? Be aware that there can also be a mixed dark and light theme and that colors can be changed by the user, so in your case it would probably be better to use the background of the specific element instead of relying on a hint or on a theme ID (as [Eclipse itself does here](https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.ui/blob/2f3a294880da4b172c6ce2bd82d7a9f4b0be8cb9/bundles/org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme/src/org/eclipse/e4/ui/css/swt/internal/theme/ThemeEngine.java#L590-L621)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Display.isSystemDarkTheme()`](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display.html#isSystemDarkTheme()) returns only a hint, whether a dark or a light theme is set in the operating system which might be differ from the theme set in Eclipse. See [Javadoc](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display.html#isSystemDarkTheme()):

> Note: This operation is a hint and is not supported on platforms that
> do not have this concept.

Be aware that there can also be a mixed dark and light theme and that colors can be changed by the user, so **in your case** it would probably be **better** to **use the background color** (or even more precise, comparing the lightness of the foreground/text color vs. the lightness of the background color) **of the specific element** instead of relying on a hint or on a theme ID (as [Eclipse itself does here](https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.ui/blob/2f3a294880da4b172c6ce2bd82d7a9f4b0be8cb9/bundles/org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme/src/org/eclipse/e4/ui/css/swt/internal/theme/ThemeEngine.java#L590-L621), for example).